# Are we ready for a Blog?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Apparently, StackExchange sites can include their blogs (as [mentioned on BlogOverflow](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/)).

**Would you be interested in such a blog for Tridion Stack Exchange?**

If so, offer an answer including what you'd be interested in reading about or possibly contributing. We'd probalby want to narrow the scope to something reasonable and start slowly.

If not, feel free to answer why we shouldn't add a blog to the growing list of blogs (Bart Koopman started a list of current [SDL Tridion-related blogs on TridionWorld](http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/community_power.aspx)).

**Update:** point was to see if we'd contribute and or follow (even if accidentally by search) such a blog. It looks like we would.

I'm not looking to kill TridionDeveloper (sorry, Chris) and I'll leave this up as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I don't see the need for creating yet another blog (certainly not if its intention is to replace [tridiondeveloper.com](http://tridiondeveloper.com) and everybody's personal blog).

I think most of us will rather blog on a personal blog anyways and those (like me) that didn't bother creating a personal blog, we jumped in on [tridiondeveloper.com](http://tridiondeveloper.com). Don't get me wrong, I'm not against it and I think its a nice thought to try and keep everything in a single location, but it didn't seem to have worked that much in the past.

Look for instance at [sdltridionworld.com](http://sdltridionworld.com), that was also designed as a single location allowing people to send in their articles. Agreed it has a higher threshold than a blog but the amount of articles sent in have been very low over the years.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe different blogs for different messages or audiences? I tend to make three types of posts: functional posts, some about code (on TridionDeveloper), and community observations. If we have a blog here, I'd likely make posts about the community here.

Comment: That makes sense, like I said, not against another blog, by all means keep em coming. Just think it's wrong to start it off as a replacement of something that is not flawed.

Comment: I concur, I'll leave in the [meta-tag:feature-request] and think of it as an option for the tech community.

Answer (score 2):

I say yes. Not sure who owns TridionDeveloper.com or any of the other blogs but in my opinion a community blog should be owned by the community. I'd certainly want to contribute from time to time but I've never felt the need to start my personal blog (as you so accurately stated: why create yet-another-personal-blog-on-tridion?).

Comment: tridiondeveloper.com is made available by Content Bloom and I guess the only thing really missing there is an about section telling you how to ask for an account, but most community members know how to reach the owners so far I guess ;o).
However I value your statement and agree that if you see a blog of Stack Exchange more open to start off with, then by all means we should create it!

Comment: We probably have a lot of personal blogs because they're easy to make, use the platform or sign-on we prefer (Wordpress? Google Blogger?), and let us customize them to the style and message we want. Portability and some SEO goodness are nice career or "personal branding" benefits. ;-) I finally rank higher in search than the thousands of other "Alvin Reyi."

Answer (score 1):

I say yes. Time to kill off TridionDeveloper.com as a common platform. Count me in. One Blog to rule them all.

Answer (score 1):

Fantastic idea, we should have a blog for this site so all the expertise is there and helping people immensely.

Regarding topics, I would say more exploration on 2013, More on storage extension, processors etc. would be great.